# Not sure im doing sql queries correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, natural-join

```
department(dept_name, building, budget)

course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits)

instructor(ID, name, dept_name, salary)

section(course_id, sec_id, semester, year, building, room_number, time_slot_id)

teaches(ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year)

student(ID, name, dept_name, tot_cred)

takes(ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade)
```

1. Find the course title, semester and year of each course that was taken by more than 50 students

   ```
   select course.title , takes.semester , takes.year
   from course
   natural join takes
   where course.course_id = takes.course_id
   having count(distinct ID) > 50
   ```
2. Find the title of each course that had more than one section

   ```
   select title 
   from course
   natural join section 
   where course.course_id = section.course_id
   having count(distinct sec_id) > 1
   ```
3. Find the IDs of all instructors who taught more than 5 courses in the Comp. Sci. department

   ```
   select ID
   from instructor
   natural join course
   where course.dept_name = instructor. dept_name
   having count(credits)>5
   ```

Also should this be credits or course_id

4. Find all instructors who didn’t teach any module offered by the Biology department

This one I don’t even no where to start

Comment: dont use natural join ( it relies on implicit field names ). also cant have having clause without group by..

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server? They're not the same, or even related.

Comment: @amdixon I think MySQL allows HAVING without GROUP BY. But he needs GROUP BY for these queries, because he wants to count within the groups.

Comment: correct, in this context he needs a group by but mysql allows it syntactically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your queries are missing `GROUP BY` clauses.

And if you use `NATURAL JOIN`, you don't need a `WHERE` clause to relate the tables -- `NATURAL JOIN` does that automatically.

```
select course.title , takes.semester , takes.year
from course
natural join takes
GROUP BY course.title, takes.semester, takes.year    
having count(distinct ID) > 50

select title 
from course
natural join section 
GROUP BY title
having count(distinct sec_id) > 1

select ID
from instructor
natural join course
GROUP BY ID
having count(credits)>5
```

Your last query has several other problems. You're not linking the instructor to the course using the `teaches` table, and you're not checking whether the course is in the Comp. Sci. department.

```
SELECT i.id
FROM instructor AS i
JOIN teaches AS t ON i.id = t.sec_id
JOIN course AS c ON t.course_id = c.id
WHERE c.dept_name = "Comp. Sci."
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(t.id), c.title , t.semester , t.year
from course c
left join takes t on t.cource_id=c.cource_id
group by 2,3,4
having count(t.id) > 50

select c.title, count(s.sec_id) 
from course c
left join section  s on c.course_id = s.course_id
group by 1
having count(s.sec_id) > 1

select i.ID, count(c.id)
from instructor i
left join course c on c.dept_name = i. dept_name
group by 1
having count(c.id)>5

select i.ID
from instructor i
left join department d on d.dept_name=i.dept_name
where d.dept_name<>'Biology'
```